# Better performance in calculating E

Tags: java, performance, mathematics

Can you give me some performance advice on how to optimize the time of execution of the following calculation of E?

```
package calculatee;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class CalculateE {
 static long start1 = System.nanoTime();

 public static BigDecimal factorial(int x) {
    BigDecimal prod = new BigDecimal("1");
    for (int i = x; i > 1; i--) {
        prod = prod.multiply(new BigDecimal(i));
    }
    return prod;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal e = BigDecimal.ONE;
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        e = e.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(3 * i, 2) + 1).divide(factorial(3 * i),new MathContext(10000, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
    }
    System.out.println("e = " + e);
    long stop = System.nanoTime();
    long diff = stop - start1;
    System.out.println(diff + " ns");
 }

}
```

The time of execution is about 3055588556 ns.

Answer (score 3):

you can split up the calculation in your `for` loop into threads and sum up the results afterwards: here an example for 4 Threads: Use as many Threads as you have `CPU`s. It's important to add the result inside a `synchronized` block, otherwise you result could be corrupted by [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). I get a speed up of 50% with 4 threads compared to a single core execution.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class CalculateE {

    static long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    static BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE;

    public static BigDecimal factorial(int x) {
        BigDecimal prod = new BigDecimal("1");
        for (int i = x; i > 1; i--) {
            prod = prod.multiply(new BigDecimal(i));
        }
        return prod;
    }

    public static Runnable getRunner(final int from, final int to) {
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BigDecimal e = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
                    e = e.add(BigDecimal
                            .valueOf(Math.pow(3 * i, 2) + 1)
                            .divide(factorial(3 * i),
                                    new MathContext(10000, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
                }
                addResult(e);
            }
        };
        return runner;
    }

    public static synchronized void addResult(BigDecimal e){
        result = result.add(e);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r1 = getRunner(1, 251);
        Runnable r2 = getRunner(251, 501);
        Runnable r3 = getRunner(501, 751);
        Runnable r4 = getRunner(751, 1000);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t2.start();
        Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
        t3.start();
        Thread t4 = new Thread(r4);
        t4.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
        System.out.println("e = " + result);
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = stop - start1;
        System.out.println(diff + " ms");
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice that you say use as many processors as you have.  Pitty you don't make it generic by asking the pc his available processors by using : `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();` and using one AtomicInteger what you use in the 4 threads for counting to the end, so if one thread crash, the other ones shall continue to do the whole work.

Comment: @chillworld why would one thread crash, and why is it ok to continue if it did?

Comment: In this example normally there shall not be a crash, but this is a system you can use for every task splitting. The advantage is also that your x threads finish simultane, what is maybe not true when you split it in x equal divisions.

Comment: @chillworld Good point. It is unlikely that the work is the same for all threads.

Comment: Sometimes optimising the code gives you more improvement than using more threads.

Comment: Although you might want to use an [`AtomicBigDecimal`](http://www.coderanch.com/t/566492/threads/java/AtomicBigDecimal-class-interesting-find) instead of using synchronized blocks.

Comment: Also, why are you constructing a brand new `MathContext` in each iteration of the loop? You should  just reuse a single instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is 4.5x faster than the original code.

On my machine, the single threaded version was about the same speed as the multi-threaded version I wrote. The single thread version was much simpler.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class CalculateE {
    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        BigDecimal e = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal factorial = BigDecimal.ONE;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            long x = i * 3;
            factorial = factorial.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(x * (x - 1) * (x - 2)));
            e = e.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(9L * i * i + 1).divide(factorial, 9200, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("e = " + e);
        System.out.println("Took " + time / 1e9 + " seconds to calculate");
    }
}
```

prints

```
e = 2.7.....
Took 0.796560819 seconds to calculate
```

Note: running the multi-threaded example above reported

```
2626 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

A standalone `factorial()` function is always a big red flag. Same goes for `pow()`. When calculating power series most often they just not needed.

Consider a Horner schema instead (pseudocode below):

In a most straightforward way, without using `3i` trick, the calculation would looks like

```
e = 1.0
for i = N, i > 0, i -= 1
    e = 1.0 + e/i
```

No factorials, no powers.

If using the trick, I'd first split the formula into two sums:

```
e = sum(1 / (3i)!) + sum((3i)**2 / (3i)!)
```

calculate them independently, and add the results. The first schema is a trivial adaptation of the above one; the second one is just a bit more involved:

```
result = 1.0
for i = 3*N, i > 0, i -= 3
    result = i*i * (1.0 + result/(i*(i-1)*(i-2)))
```

No factorials, no powers. No need for big integers as well.

PS: the biggest problem with the Horner schema is estimating the iteration count for the desired accuracy. Sometimes a heavy math is necessary. In such a simple case like `e` it is almost trivial.